# Sensitivity of the test for variance to the assumption of normality

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I want to create a simulation in Rstudio that will check the sensitivity of the test for variance to the assumption of normality. Can this be done without using var.test? Should I draw a few samples from the normal distribution and a few from a different distribution and count p.value?

Comment: If you think skewness or excess kurtosis are potential issues, best to vary those and perform Monte Carlo simulations, checking on the type I error rate (and/or power).